# How to use wijmo with Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, wijmo

Can someone provide a practical way of getting Wijmo working with Rails 3.1

I would think the best way would be to dump the downloaded Wijmo folder and all of its contents in the `vender/assets` directory and then somehow only referencing the files that are needed. But the asset pipeline is a bit picky and wants to load ALL files (including development files etc).

I guess I should really be doing my homework properly and thoroughly understanding the assets pipeline, but I would appreciate if someone could show me a fast and clean way of getting a vanilla Rails 3.1 app up and running with Wijmo installed. I would need the solution to cover both development and production mode.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, The best way would be to just reference the scripts/stylesheets needed in a page using CDN. You can reference it in a layout template so it can be used anywhere.

You can get the reference snippet to use here: http://wijmo.com/downloads/cdn/

You also might want to try referencing the v2 Beta since there are now fewer references.